# liquibase generateChangeLog Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgres

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to run liquibase to generate a changelog of my current database, but I get the following error and not sure how to get around it.

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgres://kbjoxiifqvunac:ef1f6ba0b9633d5951c6f4a28897fe390fdf2a7f4189320569d303531899e843@ec2-54-217-235-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d1pdhars1kb6ep with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgres://kbjoxiifqvunac:ef1f6ba0b9633d5951c6f4a28897fe390fdf2a7f4189320569d303531899e843@ec2-54-217-235-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d1pdhars1kb6ep with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:135) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:977) [liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:209) [liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:132) [liquibase.jar:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgres://kbjoxiifqvunac:ef1f6ba0b9633d5951c6f4a28897fe390fdf2a7f4189320569d303531899e843@ec2-54-217-235-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d1pdhars1kb6ep with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:259) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:149) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:100) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgres://kbjoxiifqvunac:ef1f6ba0b9633d5951c6f4a28897fe390fdf2a7f4189320569d303531899e843@ec2-54-217-235-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d1pdhars1kb6ep with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:254) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I have run the following command

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --url=jdbc:postgres://user:password@ec2-54-217-235-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/dbhost generateChangeLog
```

I have omitted the classpath flag since I put the postgres drivers inside the lib folder of my liquibase, and per documentation it should scan it.

I'm running on windows, liquibase version 3.8.0 and postgres-drivers 42.1.1. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think your driver jar should be in the `lib` directory rather than the `bin` directory. If you look at these lines from `liquibase.bat` you can see that it adds all jar files in the `bin` directory that start with `liquibase`, and then ***ALL*** jar files that are in the `lib` directory.

```
set CP=.
for /R %LIQUIBASE_HOME% %%f in (liquibase*.jar) do set CP=!CP!;%%f
for /R %LIQUIBASE_HOME%\lib %%f in (*.jar) do set CP=!CP!;%%f
```

Comment: it's my bad, it was already in the lib folder, I made a mistake while writing the post